# CS50 Tideman Locking

Tags: cs50

So i am trying to figure our something i have seen so far as some solutions for the Tideman problem from the CS50 course. My doubt is the following>>

We have this code>>

```
// Test for cycle by checking arrow coming into each candidate
bool cycle(int end, int cycle_start)
{
    // Return true if there is a cycle created (Recursion base case)
    if (end == cycle_start)
    {
        return true;
    }
    // Loop through candidates (Recursive case)
    for (int i = 0; i < candidate_count; i++)
    {
        if (locked[end][i])
        {
            if (cycle(i, cycle_start))
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

In this case on the line >>

```
if (locked[end][i])
```

My understanding is that it means locked[end][i] is true, which means there is an arrow there. I think i get that.

But i remember that the Locked array Locked[max][max] has false as the value for each pair locked it has.

Considering that all pairs are "false", then my understanding is that the condition here>>

```
if (locked[end][i])
```

won't be met ever since everything is false always before passing through the check cycle function.

Am i wrong? If so, please help me understand how the recursive function works here.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

lock_pairs which calls cycle sets edges to true as it finds them, thus all are false only on the first edge check.